# Time Series Preprocessing

Tags: regression, time-series, arima, lstm, data-preprocessing

I am just here for brainstorming as time series prediction can be storming to the brain.

so basically working with time series prediction doesn't usually follow the same rules as working with other kinds of data and i have went through alot of blogs and books from ARIMA to LSTMs over the last year, yet i feel like i know nothing about time series whenever it comes to code, always new properties.

maybe i can summarize my struggles as below and hopefully someone have ideas or guidance regarding those points:-

How to account for unseen data ? if the data has a moving center, so the future data will be different from the training data, could i use some sort of scaling ?

Inability to remove the outliers as they maybe data themselves, maybe a clipping function for data that has large difference of its neighbors ?

Using Moving Average (Exponential Moving Average) would be easier to predict, but we should know that we're predicting something near the original not the actual data.

The loss of data when normalizing for prediction and de-normalizing the predicted data on an out-of-dataset

I hope the questions are not dumb and thanks in advance